# Testing AngularJS controller with Jasmine

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, karma-jasmine

I have the following NewPageCtrl.js

```
angular.module('NewPageCtrl', []).controller('NewPageController', function($scope, $document) {

    $scope.showMe = false;

});
```

And the following test.js

```
describe('NewPageCtrl', function() {
var scope, $document, createController;

beforeEach(inject(function ($rootScope, $controller _$document_) {
    $document = _$document_;
    scope = $rootScope.$new();

    createController = function() {
        return $controller('NewPageCtrl', {
            '$scope': scope
        });
    };
}));

it('should check showMe', function() {

});
});
```

I will write the test case later, but for now Jasmine is giving me the error:

```
 Chrome 48.0.2564 (Mac OS X 10.10.5) ERROR
 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
 at /Users/me/myProject/test/test.js:23
```

Line 23 is the beforeEach(... line

I got the example from http://nathanleclaire.com/blog/2013/12/13/how-to-unit-test-controllers-in-angularjs-without-setting-your-hair-on-fire/

Comment: Change `$rootScope, $controller _$document_` to `$rootScope, $controller, _$document_`, comma missing!

Comment: Funny it's also on the page :)

Comment: Fantastic! Well spotted. Post an answer and ill mark it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You missed a comma.

Change

```
$rootScope, $controller _$document_
```

to

```
$rootScope, $controller, _$document_
```